# Orthogonal matrix is unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix lies in $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ why does it also ly in $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$?

If a real matrix $A$ hat determinant $\neq 0$ then its determinant as a complex matrix is also non zero since the determinant depends not on the field.

That's it, isn't it?

Comment: Your post is different than your title

Comment: Yes but this is the main point. If I have $A^t=A^{-1}$ then of course I do have $A^*=A^{-1}$ for real $A$.

Comment: @user455297 I agree with you on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's it.
You can also write  $  AB = BA = I_n  $ , and as real matrices are also complex ones, if $ A $ is invertible as a real matrix, it is also invertible as a complex one.

Comment: And in the same way, if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries and satisfies $AA^T=A^TA=I_n$, then seen as a complex matrix that is $AA^*=A^*A=I_n$ where asterisk denotes the conjugate transpose (a.k.a. Hermitian adjoint) of a matrix. This shows that if a real matrix is orthogonal, then when seen as a complex matrix it is unitary (the question title).

Answer (score 0):

It is common to say that $\Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$.  In particular, we identify the real number $x \in \Bbb R$ with the complex number $x + 0i \in \Bbb C$.